# TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT vs. TRUNCATE?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, truncate, snapshot-isolation

I'm hoping someone can shed some light on this behavior that I was not expecting regarding SNAPSHOT isolation vs. TRUNCATE.

Database: Allow Snapshot Isolation = True; Is Read Committed Snapshot On = False.

Procedure1 (Replaces content of table foo from a long-running complex SELECT with lots of joins):

```
BEGIN TRAN; 
TRUNCATE TABLE foo; 
INSERT INTO foo SELECT...; 
COMMIT;
```

Procedure2 (Reads from table foo):

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT; 
SELECT * FROM foo;
```

If Procedure1 is running while Procedure2 is executed, Procedure2 is held up with a LCK_M_SCH_S wait (according to sp_WhoIsActive) until Procedure1 finishes. And when Procedure2 does complete, it raises this exception:

> Snapshot isolation transaction failed in database 'DatabaseName'
>   because the object accessed by the statement has been modified by a
>   DDL statement in another concurrent transaction since the start of
>   this transaction. It is disallowed because the metadata is not
>   versioned. A concurrent update to metadata can lead to inconsistency
>   if mixed with snapshot isolation.

However, Microsoft does not list TRUNCATE as a DDL statement not permitted under SNAPSHOT isolation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933783.aspx

Clearly I'm not understanding something correctly, as I would have expected a best case of Procedure2 immediately returning the most recently committed data from the table before the TRUNCATE or a worst case of being held up by Procedure1 and then returning the new content of the table. Can you help?

Comment: Can you use DELETE FROM foo instead? That won't place the schema lock.

Comment: DELETE FROM is indeed the way I am working around this. I am also interested in why I am getting the error (and only after Procedure1 returns).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The list of `'DDL'` operations listed is not comprehensive (and `TRUNCATE TABLE` is not the only omission from that list). Whether `TRUNCATE TABLE` is `DML` or `DDL` is a fraught question in SQL Server, with persuasive examples on both sides of the debate, and entries both ways in Books Online.

From the point of view of a snapshot isolation transaction, truncate has the essential quality of [taking a `Sch-M` lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175519.aspx), which explains the blocking ( because [`RCSI` and `SI` still acquire `Sch-S` locks](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189050.aspx)); and it also bumps the internal metadata version (for internal reasons*) resulting in error 3961.

So, the behaviour you are seeing is expected, just not documented very well.

* <sub>The current implementation of TRUNCATE TABLE does not generate row versions. Bumping the metadata version is the simplest way to ensure correct behaviour.</sub>